# Java Swing - resize Dialog on JLabel.setVisible(...)

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a Java Swing Dialog with a **hidden** JLabel above each input component (i.e. JTextField). The purpose of this hidden JLabel is to use it as validation output for its input component.

Let's say, there is an input field for the description of some entity, which has to be non empty, and should contain some special stuff. On error, the action could call the following method:

```
private void invalidateDescription(String errMessage) {
    errDescriptionLabel.setText(errMessage);                      
    errDescriptionLabel.setVisible(true);
    descriptionTextField.setBackground(ERR_COLOR);
}
```

After that, I call `pack()` and `invalidate()`

The problem is, that the JDialog still has the same vertical size, so that some of the components (the buttons in the bottom of the dialog) disapear (because they're out of view).

Do you have any suggestion how to fix it?

Best Regards.

edit: I forgott to mention, that the JDialog has a "Free Design" Layout (Netbeans GUI Builder default).
edit 2: I'm looking for a solution which doesn't require kind of a placeholder for (error) JLabel. "Empty Space" is not a desired solution because the dialog doesn't look balanced.

Comment: A better answer will require a lot more context regarding your program's validation strategy. Have you considered adding a status panel to your layout or using `InputVerifier`?

Comment: Swing doesn't do multiple hidden components well.  One option is to have one JLabel at the top of bottom for all of your error messages, although you can only display one error message at a time.  Another alternative is to have a 3 column form, where the 3rd column is reserved for error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CardLayout` place your labesl and empty `JPanels` ans swap thm when necessary.

Comment: You mean to put a stack (CardLayout) of the error label and an empty panel above each input component and to swap them if necessary? How is that solution better then just placing the JLabel (for the error message) without a text in it above the input component and fill the text in on error? Anyway, the problem is still the same: you have some kind of placeholder, so that the dialogs look unbalanced (weird) -> not a desired solution

Comment: CardLayout cares about space. Swapping cards doesn't change space used in layout. You can try to place 2 labels in CardLayout (long and short) and swap them. So size of dialog won't change but if there is no error you will see empty space for the label under filler JPanel.

Comment: Right, and exactly that empty space is the problem (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `setVisible()`, give `errDescriptionLabel` a background color that matches that of the enclosing panel when the entry is valid.

Comment: Thank you. But take a look on my comment to StanislavL answer (above). Yours, his and my solution (in the comment above) still requires some kind of a placeholder (or the JLabel itself). The dialog is not balanced and looks weird.

Comment: Update your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Java Swing Dialog with a hidden JLabel above each input component

I would not use a hidden component for this. I would change:

```
private void invalidateDescription(String errMessage)
```

to

```
private void invalidateDescription(String errMessage, component inputComponent)
```

Then I would display a popup with the error message. You could use a non-decorated JDialog as the popup. You might even be able to use a JPopupMenu as the popup.

When you display the popup you would position the popup releative to the input component.